# Python PDB Debugger (code working in debugger but not in SciTE)

Tags: python-2.7, vpython

I have a problem with the Python PDB Debugger and my code written in SciTE.

So I have a class called "func". This class has a method called "hermite". I am using the PDB Debugger to figure out why my program is freezing whenever it is executing this method.

I start with:

```
pdb.set_trace()
func.hermite(a,b,c)
```

The program freezes when I press "n", to go to the next line in the debugger.

If I put `pdb.set_trace()` inside the method "hermite", I get:

```
def hermite(a,b,c):
    pdb.set_trace()
    .... (stuff here)
```

In the debugger now, the method executes completely, with no problems at all.

I have no clue why the debugger would freeze when the method is called, but then when
`set_trace` is put inside the method the program runs just fine. Also, in SciTE, no matter
`where set_trace()` is put, the program does not run. So its as if the program will only run
from the debugger, with set_trace inside the method, for some reason.

Any ideas on what the problem is? I would paste the code for "hermite" but it is very long. I think
the important part is that it executes perfectly fine when `set_trace` is inside the method, but it freezes when `set_trace` is outside it.

**UPDATE**:
Nevermind I have solved the problem. Inside my hermite method, I was time stepping a differential equation and I was using (15 - (-15)) / 100 as my time step interval, and python was flooring that value to 0, so it was running indefinitely. The reason why the program worked in the the debugger was because I was forcing the time step to a non zero value to get the execution time to be small. Thanks anyways to anyone who saw this.